# View page is taking lot of time to load

Tags: 7, views, performance

I have developed an application using Drupal 7, where I have created views and it has lots of data. Now its taking lot of time to load the page and all users are complaining about this issue.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this performance issue? I will be very thankful if someone answer to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using pager in that page and approximately whats the record count of your view ?

Comment: @visabhishek:Thanks for replaying me:) Pagination i followed, well 1000 of records will be there

Comment: @neethu how many results are you displaying per page?

Comment: @NoSssweat:Hello, I am displaying 15 now ,before i was displaying 50 items since system is very slow i reduced to 15 items,its night mare to me

Comment: @Neethu, do you have authenticated users? (logged in users) or are your users anonymous users (not logged in)?

Comment: yes users are authenticated, myself as admin if i login it taking time to load the page,10000 of records are there

Comment: On the view edit page hit the preview button; that will output the query; add the query to your question.

Comment: just install "xhprof" profiling in your site. It will show the amount of time taken to execute the functions and queries. By doing this you can easily find why your site performance is low

Comment: @user15837: Thanks a lot i will check with this.btw my site is not slow:) only one view page where in it has 5000 records in it

Answer (score 1):

#### Install and use [Views Litepager](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_litepager)

> Though this pager may appear similar to View's "Mini Pager" option, it
> is functionally different in a very important way. **The Views Litepager
> module solves a problem of scalability for sites with large amounts of
> content.** Drupal's core pagination system creates a pager navigation
> that shows exactly how many pages of content exist for the content
> list. This requires that a COUNT query be executed based on the query
> used to generate the list.

#### Enable Caching

[image]

#### In Drupal Performance settings

Enable aggregate css and js.

[image]